# Hive lateral view two list columns

Tags: hive

I have a table looks like this:

```
product    quantitylist    pricelist
product1   [1,10,100]      [3,2,1]
product2   [1]             [3]
product3   [1,10]          [3,1]
```

I want the output like this:

```
product    quantity        price
product1   1               3
product1   10              2
product1   100             1
product2   1               3
product3   1               3
product3   10              1
```

I tried to use lateral view but when I use lateral view with multiple list columns, it start to build all the permutations and combinations.. which resulted in tons of duplicates.

```
SELECT
   *
FROM p1part 
LATERAL VIEW explode(quantitylist) adTable AS quantity
LATERAL VIEW explode(pricelist) adTable1 AS price
```

It gave me:

```
product    quantity        price
product1   1               3
product1   1               2
product1   1               1
product1   10              3
product1   10              2
product1   10              1
product1   100             3
product1   100             2
product1   100             1
...
```

Can anyone show me how to do it properly?

Answer (score 4):

You can try

```
SELECT
   *
FROM p1part 
LATERAL VIEW posexplode(quantitylist) adTable AS p1,quantity
LATERAL VIEW posexplode(pricelist) adTable1 AS p2,price
WHERE p1=p2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because that the first `lateral view` gives you the combination of every `quantity` value with the `price` array.

I will try to use the `transform`.

1.Add a python script as `transer.py`

```
#coding=utf8
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    product, quantitylist, pricelist = line.strip().split('\t')
    quantitylist = quantitylist.split(',')
    pricelist = pricelist.split(',')
    if len(quantitylist) != len(pricelist):
        continue
    for i in range(len(quantitylist)):
        print "\t".join([product, quantitylist[i], pricelist[i]])
```

2.Before your hive query, add this script by

```
add file transer.py;
```

3.Run the transform by

```
select transform(product, quantitylist, pricelist)
using 'python transer.py'
as (product, quantity, price)
from YOUR_TABLE_NAME
```

BTW. you can also try to write a UDTF yourself.